# How can I average every 5 rows specific column and select last data from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas df with say, 100 rows, 4 columns. I want to calculate mean in specific columns("Value") every 5 rows and select last data(Fifth) of another column("Date") to keep in new dataframe.

My dataframe that looks like this :

```
>>df
       DateTime     Product     Location       Value
0    12-07-2018           A           S1       1.313
1    12-07-2018           B           S1       3.089
2    12-07-2018           C           S1       1.890
3    12-07-2018           D           S1       3.136
4**  12-07-2018           E           S1       3.258
5    13-07-2018           F           S1       3.113
6    13-07-2018           G           S1       2.651
7    13-07-2018           H           S1       2.135
8    13-07-2018           I           S1       1.555
9**  14-07-2018           J           S1       2.009
10   14-07-2018           K           S1       1.757
11   14-07-2018           L           S1       1.808
12   14-07-2018           M           S1       1.511
13   15-07-2018           N           S1       2.265
14** 15-07-2018           O           S1       2.356
15   15-07-2018           P           S1       2.950
16   15-07-2018           Q           S1       3.300
```

Now I can average every 5 rows by this code :

```
> new_df = df.groupby(df.index // 5).agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean'})
```

This result of code :

```
>> new_df
     DateTime        Value
0  12-07-2018       2.5372
1  14-07-2018       2.2926
2  15-07-2018       1.9394
3  15-07-2018       3.1250
```

But last 2 rows was average with same. (2.950+3.300)/2 = 3.1250. If it has 1,2,3,4 row, it will average on the number of row.

I would like to average 5 rows only. If it hasn't 5 rows, don't average and send to **new_df**

How can I do that?

**Note : I add ** for easy to observe at every 5 rows.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best understanding, your request is equivalent to truncating `df` to a length divisible by 5 before aggregating. You can use slicing on the fly:

```
new_df = df.groupby(df[:(len(df)//5)*5].index // 5).agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean'})
```

Comment: I use your code but VSC call ValueError : Grouper and axis must be same length.
I try to change code to new code is new_df = df[:(len(df)//5)*5].groupby(df[:(len(df)//5)*5].index // 5).agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean'}). 
It can work !
Thanks many.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
i = df.index // 5
#compare by last value
mask = i == i[-1]
#length of last group
no = mask.sum()

#filter only if last group less as 5
no = mask.sum()
if no < 5:
    df = df[~mask]
```

Another idea:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index // 5)
df = df[s.groupby(s).transform('count') == 5]
```

---

```
new_df = df.groupby(df.index // 5).agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean'})
print (new_df)
     DateTime   Value
0  12-07-2018  2.5372
1  14-07-2018  2.2926
2  15-07-2018  1.9394
```

Comment: I forgot describe about df row at 15 16 don't send to new_df (5 rows only).
I'll edit my post. Sorry sir.

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - It is different  ;) check edited answer.

Comment: Your solution worked for me! Thank you very much. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Can I use aggregate to select ({'DateTime':'last', 'Value':'mean'}, 'Product':'all') for show Product A,B,C,D,E // F,G,H,I,J, when group every 5 rows?